# Fast algorithm mapping int to monotonically increasing int subset

Tags: c, algorithm

I have encountered variations of this problem multiple times, and most recently it became a bottleneck in my arithmetic coder implementation. Given N (<= 256) segments of known non-negative size S<sub>i</sub> laid out in order starting from the origin, and for a given x, I want to find n such that

`S0 + S1 + ... + Sn-1 <= x < S0 + S1 + ... + Sn`

The catch is that lookups and updates are done at about the same frequency, and almost every update is in the form of increasing the size of a segment by 1. Also, the bigger a segment, the higher the probability it will be looked up or updated again.

Obviously some sort of tree seems like the obvious approach, but I have been unable to come up with any tree implementation that satisfactorily takes advantage of the known domain specific details.

Given the relatively small size of N, I also tried linear approaches, but they turned out to be considerably slower than a naive binary tree (even after some optimization, like starting from the back of the list for numbers above half the total)

Similarly, I tested introducing an intermediate step that remaps values in such a way as to keep segments ordered by size, to make access faster for the most frequently used, but the added overhead exceeded gains.

Sorry for the unclear title -- despite it being a fairly basic problem, I am not aware of any specific names for it.

Comment: Very interesting, i wonder how matlab implement it.

Comment: Can you expand on the "almost" in "almost every update is in the form of increasing the size of a segment by 1"? What other possibilities are there? Adding/deleting segments? Incrementing by more than 1? Decrementing?

Comment: Also, did you try the binary tree where each node contains the total size of its left subtree, as well as its own segment size? That could be hardcoded for 256 segments with a maximum of eight accesses to update or find any segment.

Comment: as N is relatively small why not remember the sum instead of `s(i)` or keep booth  of them then you need just single binary search

Comment: What does it mean that segments are *'laid out in order starting from the origin'*? Are they in ordered by their lengths? Are they ordered by they position in some space? What space is it – are they placed along a line? How are they ordered then: by their midpoints positions? by their left endpoints or by their right endpoints? Can they overlap? How are segments ordered when they are on both sides of the 'origin' - are those on negative side placed first, then those on positive side, or are they interleved just by a distanse without regarding the side?...

Comment: ...or possibly they are always all on one side of 'origin'? Does it matter at all there are any 'segments' in your original problem, or it is sufficient to consider any array of numbers `S[]`...?

Comment: @rici By almost, I'm thinking of the case when the sum of all segments will overflow an uint32 on the next increase. In that case, all segment sizes become `max(1, previousSize / 2)`. It's a very rare case so performance is not of concern (within reason). As for your binary tree suggestion, that is basically my current implementation. While performance is not terrible, it's still the bottleneck, and it's not quite fast enough yet, so I was hoping for better ideas.

Comment: @CiaPan I may have just made matters more confusing by referring to them as segments. They are simply ordered by index. Given that S[i] is a non-negative integer, as long as the formula in the question holds, you may interpret what it means "physically" as makes the most sense to you (i.e. an array of numbers S[] is just fine)

Comment: @Spektre That results in fast lookup, but then update becomes much more expensive (to increase S[n] by 1, you need to increase the sums of all n <= x < totalCount by 1)

Comment: Note if the S1...Sn are (very) unevenly distributed (such as power-law distribution), it helps to put the larger ones at the front and just do a sequential search to find the partial sum(assuming that x is uniform). Keeping them sorted can be done periodically, or by doing a "partial bubblesort" after an element is updated (the movement caused by an update is relatively small)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose some BST would do... You may try to add a new numeric member (`int` or `long`) to each node to keep a sum of values of all left descendants. Then you'll seek for each item in approximately logarithmic time, and once an item is added, removed or modified you'll have to update just its ancestors on the returning path from the recursion. You may apply some self-organizing tree structure, for example AVL to keep the worst-case search optimal or a splay tree to optimize searches for those most often used items. Take care to update the left-subtree-sums during rebalancing or splaying.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a binary tree where each node n contains two integers A_n
and U_n, where initially
A_n = S_0 + .. S_n and U_n = 0.

Let, at any fixed subsequent time, T_n = S_0 + .. + S_n.

When looking for the place of a query x, you would go along the tree, knowing that for each node m the current corresponding value of T_m is A_m + U_m + sum_{p : ancestors of m, we visited the right child of p to attain m} U_p.
This solves look up in O(log(N)).

For update of the n-th interval (increasing its size by y), you just look for it in the tree, increasing the value of U_m og y for each node m that you visit along the way. This also solves update in O(log(N)).